# Is $(2^a - 3^b)$ mutually prime with $(2^a - ((2^a)^{-1} \mod 3^b ) - ((3^b)^{-1} \mod 2^a))$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

Is $(2^a - 3^b)$ mutually prime with $(2^a -  {{[2^a]}^{-1}}\mod 3^b + [3^b]^{-1}\mod 2^a)$, provided that $a\geq b$ and $b>0$?

By $[2^a]^{-1}\mod 3^b$ I mean "the multiplicative inverse of $2^a\mod3^b$".

Comment: Your notation is not clear, moreover when you take mod you are in a different ring so asking if they are relatively prime in two different rings doesn't make much sense.

Comment: By $[2^a]^{-1}\mod 3^b$ I mean "the multiplicative inverse of $2^a\mod3^b$".

Comment: @JoeSlater  "Multilpicative inverse of $2^a $ mod $3^b $"-does it mean the multilicative inverse of $2^a $ in the ring integers mod $3^b $?

Comment: Yes. The least number $k$ such that ${{2^a*k} \cong 1}\mod 3^b$